# To apply Validation on Name Field in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, validation

I have used "contact-form-7' of in my Wordpress site. How we can apply Validation on Name field so that it can accept only string as character. Numeric string/number 
will not be allowed.

```
function wpcf7_is_user_name( $name )
{
 $result = preg_match( '/^[A-Za-z .]*$/', $name );
    return apply_filters( 'wpcf7_is_user_name', $result, $name );
}
```

I have added above mentioned code in Formatting.php page. But it's not working. Can please anyone assist I am working first time on Word Press.

Comment: Apply filters only takes 2 arguments: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of how to implement some custom validation and return errors in Contact Form 7:

Assuming that we have this input field in our form:

```
<p>Your Name (required)<br />
[text* your-name] </p>
```

We add this to our theme's functions.php file:

```
// our function will be called for all text and text* input fields
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'wpcs4948_validation_func', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'wpcs4948_validation_func', 10, 2 );


function wpcs4948_validation_func( $result, $tag ) {
  $type = $tag['type'];
  $name = $tag['name'];

  // check to see if the input field name matches
  if ( 'your-name' == $name ) {
     $the_value = $_POST[$name];

    // use a regular expression to compare the value against
    if ( preg_match( '/^\D*$/', $the_value )==0 ) {
        // the value does not match the regular expression
        // invalidate the form submission and display this error message
        $result->invalidate( $tag, "Name must contain only letters." );
      }
   }

return $result;
}
```

This will return an error if the `your-name` field contains numbers.

Note, that I did not use the regular expression you suggested `/^[A-Za-z .]*$/`  This is because that regular expression would reject names that have dashes and periods in them, which probably isn't what you want for a "name" field. However, if you are really interested in filtering a "username" field to only contain letters, than you can replace `/^\D*$/` with `/^[A-Za-z .]*$/`

Hope this helps!